# 2D Elastic Collisions 'Sticking' Issue

Tags: c#, 2d, collision-detection, collision

I have a simulation with multiple circles moving in 2D space.

There is collision detection between them, and the elastic collisions work 95% of the time. Occasionally however, when two balls hit each other, they stick to each other and overlap, often orbiting each other while being stuck together.

I'm unsure how to solve this problem.

My collision management function looks like this:

```
void manageCollision(Particle particleA, Particle particleB)
{
    float distanceX = particleA.Position.X - particleB.Position.X;
    float distanceY = particleA.Position.Y - particleB.Position.Y;
    double collisionAngle = Math.Atan2(distanceY, distanceX);
    double pA_magnitude = Math.Sqrt(particleA.Velocity.X * particleA.Velocity.X + particleA.Velocity.Y * particleA.Velocity.Y);
    double pB_magnitude = Math.Sqrt(particleB.Velocity.X * particleB.Velocity.X + particleB.Velocity.Y * particleB.Velocity.Y);
    double pA_direction = Math.Atan2(particleA.Velocity.Y, particleA.Velocity.X);
    double pB_direction = Math.Atan2(particleB.Velocity.Y, particleB.Velocity.X);
    double pA_newVelocityX = pA_magnitude * Math.Cos(pA_direction - collisionAngle);
    double pA_newVelocityY = pA_magnitude * Math.Sin(pA_direction - collisionAngle);
    double pB_newVelocityX = pB_magnitude * Math.Cos(pB_direction - collisionAngle);
    double pB_newVelocityY = pB_magnitude * Math.Sin(pB_direction - collisionAngle);
    double pA_finalVelocityX = ((particleA.Mass - particleB.Mass) * pA_newVelocityX + (particleB.Mass + particleB.Mass) * pB_newVelocityX) / (particleA.Mass + particleB.Mass);
    double pB_finalVelocityX = ((particleA.Mass + particleA.Mass) * pA_newVelocityX + (particleB.Mass - particleA.Mass) * pB_newVelocityX) / (particleA.Mass + particleB.Mass);
    double pA_finalVelocityY = pA_newVelocityY;
    double pB_finalVelocityY = pB_newVelocityY;
    particleA.Velocity = new Vector2((float)(Math.Cos(collisionAngle) * pA_finalVelocityX + Math.Cos(collisionAngle + Math.PI / 2) * pA_finalVelocityY), (float)(Math.Sin(collisionAngle) * pA_finalVelocityX + Math.Sin(collisionAngle + Math.PI / 2) * pA_finalVelocityY));
    particleB.Velocity = new Vector2((float)(Math.Cos(collisionAngle) * pB_finalVelocityX + Math.Cos(collisionAngle + Math.PI / 2) * pB_finalVelocityY), (float)(Math.Sin(collisionAngle) * pB_finalVelocityX + Math.Sin(collisionAngle + Math.PI / 2) * pB_finalVelocityY));
}
```

Each ball or particle spawns with a random mass and radius.

The function is called within an update type of method, like this:

```
Particle pA = particles[i];
for (int k = i + 1; k < particles.Count(); k++)
{
    Particle pB = particles[k];
    Vector2 delta = pA.Position - pB.Position;
    float dist = delta.Length();

    if (dist < particles[i].Radius + particles[k].Radius && !particles[i].Colliding && !particles[k].Colliding)
    {
        particles[i].Colliding = true;
        particles[k].Colliding = true;
        manageCollision(particles[i], particles[k]);
        particles[i].initColorTable(); // Upon collision, change the color
        particles[k].initColorTable();
        totalCollisions++;
    }
    else
    {
        particles[i].Colliding = false;
        particles[k].Colliding = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation stems from the discrete computation and big step size of duration.

When you observe the objects with some time interval dt, you can observe some intersection between two circles and call your collision method but in the next time step they may still overlap although they are going in different directions after the collision in the previous step.

To reduce this effect, you can try a lower time step size so that the overlap ratio between objects may be reduced.
As a more complicated solution, you can keep a list of your collided objects for every step and during iterations you can check this list if current intersected circles had any "affairs" in the previous step.